# Move Seekbar not smooth

Tags: android, performance, android-seekbar

I have Seekbar and I implemented source code as below:

```
        seekProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            adjustCombination(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Because function: adjustCombination(progress) need 0,2s to finish executing so when I move Seekbar, it's not smooth. So how I can fix the issue ?

Comment: if you are doing some calculation kind of work,then move that code to onStopTrackingTouch method

Comment: @DreamInBox what this adjust combination is doing? Is this function doing anything with the UI elements?

Comment: It does some calculation and show value immediately in UI. So that is reason I put it on  onProgressChanged().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can perform your background task using AsyncTask like this,

```
seekProgress.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            new getData().execute(progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

now, you have to define getData() to perform and pass the arguments whichever you required. in you case, we have to pass the progress,

```
private class getData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... progress) {
        // perform operation you want with String "progress"
        String value = "hello" + progress;
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String progressResult) {
        // do whatever you want in this thread like
        // textview.setText(progressResult)
        super.onPostExecute(progressResult);
    }
}
```

> so, PreExecute method will be executed before performing any task in background, then your doInBackground method will be called and you will get arguments pass in this method after doInBackground onPostExecute method will be called which will receive the result returned from the doInBackground method. I hope you get it.

Comment: Thank for your answer. I try to investigate and implement, your solution worked really good.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it on the UI thread.  Make a background thread instead, and handle the callback.  Then update your UI on the UI thread if needed.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // your async action
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        // update the UI (this is executed on UI thread)
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }
}.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is suited,move your calculation code in `onStopTrackingTouch()` method. This way it will only be called once when you stop sliding on the seekbar.

Comment: Thank. Because I need progress value is show on screen so it need to update continuously so I use onProgressChanged.